# How can I make a label use different strings for specified dates?

Tags: swift, string, date, uidatepicker

My idea is to make an ios-app that displays today's lunch at my work. I'm not sure how to approach this. My own thought was to have a UIDatePicker (default set to current day) and have functions that will respond to different dates. This is some code just to illustrate the ideas in my head.

```
var dateFromPicker = UIDatePicker.date
@IBOutlet weak var lunchLabel: UILabel!

func februaryFirst {
    let dateFebruaryFirst = ...
    if dateFromPicker = dateFebruaryFirst {
        lunchLabel.text = ("Fish'n chips")
    }
 }

func februarySecond {
    let dateFebruarySecond = ...
    if dateFromPicker = dateFebruarySecond {
        lunchLabel.text = ("Noodlesoup")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use DateComponents to check which day/month a certain date is. For example:

```
func februarySecond {
    // Get the day and month of the given date
    let dateFromPickerComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month], from: dateFromPicker)
    // Check whether the day and month match Feb 2
    if dateFromPickerComponents.day == 2 && dateFromPickerComponents.month == 2 {
        lunchLabel.text = ("Noodlesoup")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `switch` statement which supports multiple values:

```
let dateFromPicker = UIDatePicker.date
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day], from: dateFromPicker)
switch (components.month!, components.day!) { // first month then day
  case (1,14): print("suprise")
  case (2,1): print("Fish'n chips")
  case (2,2): print("Noodlesoup")

  default: print("fast day")

}
```